# Diffence in size of body and image

Tags: javascript, html

I created a html document and add an image in body. When I check the height of the image and that of body, I found they have different height. Sample can be viewed [here](https://cges30901.github.io/test/multicolumn/size). Here is html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
var el = document.getElementById('test');
console.log(el.scrollHeight,el.offsetHeight,el.clientHeight)
console.log(document.body.scrollHeight,document.body.offsetHeight,document.body.clientHeight)
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<img id="test" src="img2.png"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Console output:

```
768 768 768
774 774 774
```

Why they are different? How can I make them the same or adjust the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because img is an inline element by default, and the vertical-align will be baseline by default, which means its bottom will be at the same line of bottom of "x" character. Although there's not x or other text, but it will be aligned as if there is.

So three methods to avoid this scenario are:

1. Add style "display:block" to the img, so that the vertical-align will be inefficient
2. Change style "vertical-align" to top、middle or bottom to the img, so that the area under baseline will not enlarge container
3. Add style "font-size:0" to the body, so that the height under baseline will be 0 too

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap the img inside a div element and set the div to be `display:flex` then it will wrap the image and then I believe its scrollHeight will be the same as the image.

I've never changed the display property of the body, maybe that would work as well? I don't know exactly what you are trying to accomplish so I don't know if what I'm telling you would work for you

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want images to be inline.